# Backup and Truncate-Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, backup, database-backups

I have a requirement that there is one MySQL table with 50 million rows of data.I want to take backup of last month data and want to insert to a new table.After successful backup,that much data need to be truncated.Each second I am getting packet from a device and inserting to this table.So load everything need to be considered before doing backup.What is the efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

reset the counter and clean the table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE "table_name";
```